# floating-ui/react-dom: How to prevent tooltip pop-up from relocating based on spacing and window size?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tooltip, floating-ui

How do I make the position of the `floating-ui/react-dom` tooltip pop-up `static` [ `always next to the trigger element, either left or right based on horizontal space` ]:

[image]

Currently my tooltip pop-up position keeps changing vertically based on the vertical space, how do I stop it and make it fixed?

[image]

Here is my sandbox code:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/polished-waterfall-ilc51b

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code as text directly to the question, and [format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).